# In Cucumber.js is it possible to list all of the available steps?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

Other versions of cucumber, it is possible to dump a list of all steps.  However this is not supported in javascript.  For example:

```
cucumber -f usage --dry-run
```

If you can get access to the World object or Cucumber, I think there might be a way to list all of the regexps / functions that Cucumber uses to parse the .feature files.  Does anyone know the inner workings of the javascript version that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like such an obvious need, yet very little out there about it.  I wonder why that is?

Answer (score 2):

I found it was easier to write my own, this will require all of the steps an outputs them as they are found.

```
var container = {
    myFn: function(type, regExp, fn) {
      console.log(type +' '+regExp.toString());
    },

    Given: function(regExp, fn) {
      this.myFn('Given', regExp, fn);
    },
    Then : function(regExp, fn) {
      this.myFn('Then', regExp, fn);
    },
    When : function(regExp, fn) {
      this.myFn('When', regExp, fn);
    }
  };

var steps = require('./stepDefinitions');
steps.apply(container);


// stepDefinitions
module.exports = function() {

  this.Given(/^I run Cucumber with Protractor$/, function(next) {
    next();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use for checking which steps definitions are being used:

```
cucumber-js --require step-definitions/**/*.ts --tags \"@automated and not @skip\" --format usage
```

We don't run all our tests on every push, but we do run this check, because it helps to make sure that feature files or steps definitions didn't break because of a regex problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick command line solution to list all defined steps:

```
sed -e '/^[Given|When|Then]/!d' **/*.steps.js | sort | sed 's/, async function (.*{/)/g'
```

Breaking it down:

- `sed -e '/^[Given|When|Then]/!d' **/*.steps.js` finds all lines that start with "Given", "When" or "Then" in all files that are named `*.steps.js`.
- `sort` sorts the output.
- `sed 's/, async function (.*{/)/g'` cleans up each line by replacing ", async function(...) {" with ")"

---

**Optional: Add as an npm/yarn command**

You can add it as a script in your package.json, e.g.:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "cucumber:list": "sed -e '/^[Given|When|Then]/!d' **/*.steps.js | sort | sed 's/, async function (.*{/)/g'",
    ...
  },
```

And then call `yarn cucumber:list`.